# jQuery For page smooth scroling

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-effects

I need a jquery for page smooth scroling from top to bottom or even from bottom to top.
I have page with log list so want if some-one rotate it's mouse wheel it gives him/her smooth scrolling.
and the page conating lot's of image with differnet and names and lot's of div and anchor text
So I want smooth scrolling of whole page..!!
I tried a jquery script but it's not working with every browser.

Comment: Sorry for that currently i don't have that code..!!
I just read that on blog..!! but tried not working..
so can you help me for this

Comment: `str_replace("..!!", ".", $op);`

Comment: you don't say what's wrong with the scrollbar in your browser. The plugin posted by Ben will do what you ask if you want the scrolling to happen automatically (without user having to manually scroll)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the `scrollto` plugin? http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo